# Angular update 8.2->9.0 fails

Tags: angular

I am following the instructions set out in the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=8.2-9.0) but am experiencing problems at the first step.

On running

```
NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1 npx @angular/cli@8 update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8
```

I got the following error message back:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/init'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please delete and add node module (npm i)

Then this will work.